# Use a collection of an embedded form as data source for jqGrid

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, jqgrid

I'm an absolute newbie with Symfony2 and with jqGrid. I have a form with an embedded form for a one to many relationship, something like:

```
$builder->add('field1'...));
$builder->add('fieldn', 'collection', ...));
```

And I want to use `fieldn` as the data source for a jqGrid in my `twig.html` page but I don't know how to do it. Can anyone give me an example of how to do it?